# UITextfield to NSUserDefaults type error

Tags: ios

I have a UITextField and I wish to extract the integer value from it and put it into a NSUserdefaults.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *defaultTipPercentage;

[defaults setInteger: defaultTipPercentage forKey:@"another_key_that_you_choose"];
```

I'm getting an error saying

`Use of undeclared identifer 'defaultTipPercentage'. did you mean '_defaultTipPercentage?'`

I tried this but I get an error

`Incompatible pointer to integer conversion sending 'UITextField *_weak' to parameter of type 'NSInteger'(aka 'Int')`

Pretty much just incompatible types. I was wondering what would be a quick fix for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems.

1. You can't write a text field directly to user defaults - you need the text, or rather, the integer value of the text.
2. With a property, you either need to refer to it using self.defaultTipPercentage (which uses the getter), or _defaultTipPercentage, which refers to the backing instance variable directly. Using self.xxx syntax is generally safer.

Jenox already posted code to solve the first problem in the comments.

To also fix the second problem, you need to use property list syntax:

```
NSInteger tip = [self.defaultTipPercentage.text integerValue];
[defaults setInteger:tip forKey:@"another_key_that_you_choose"];
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSInteger tip = [self.defaultTipPercentage.text integerValue];

[defaults setInteger:tip forKey:@"another_key_that_you_choose"];`

Comment: Close, but defaultTipPercentage is a property, so it would need to be NSInteger tip = [self.defaultTipPercentage.text integerValue];

Comment: I get the same suggestion to add `_` but when i did that it worked

Comment: Im jsut starting to learn iOS dev so i have no idea what the difference is between `_` and `self`

Comment: With `_defaultTipPercentage` you would access the instance variable directly, with `self.defaultTipPercentage` you would instead access the getter method for this instance variable, which is imo a better practice.